# Looking for environment to write platform independent OPENGL code

Tags: opengl, cross-platform

This is needed for an algorithm that is to be implemented in the GPU using OpenGL. What are the popular or most recommended environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org/) is pretty good - it's a fairly low-level wrapper around OpenGL, OpenCL and OpenAL that works pretty well across platforms.

LWJGL is also used as a foundation by various higher-level graphics libraries, including [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.com/) and [Processing](http://processing.org/) (which might also be good choices for you, depending on what you need....)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how high- or low-level you need to get, [JMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/introduction/) may be up your alley. It's fairly cross-platform (Java-based).